# Open a _blank link and continue the test with Playwright

Tags: javascript, playwright

I am testing two websites that are linked between each other. I starts on website one where there is a link (_blank) to the second website. And I want to continue my test on that tab.

```
test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  const browser = await chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();

  await page.goto('https://example.io/');

  const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
   context.waitForEvent('page'),
   page.locator('a.browser-button').first().click() // Opens tab
    ])
   await newPage.waitForLoadState();
   console.log(await newPage.title());

  await page.screenshot({ path: 'test.png', fullPage: true });
  await browser.close();
});
```

So I click on the button, a new tab opens. And then I want to continue from there.
Instead I get the error:

> Timeout of 30000ms exceeded.
> context.waitForEvent('page')

I have tried as in documentation as well, dont get it to work either:
https://playwright.dev/docs/pages

Comment: You linked the python's documentation, I assume you mean the [JS one](https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-new-pages). What error message do you receive when you try the documentation sample?

Comment: your right, haha! corrected!

Comment: It timesout on context.waitForEvent('page')

Comment: have you tried to treat it as a 'popup' instead of a 'page'? https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-popups you could use [codegen](https://playwright.dev/docs/1.20/codegen) to see how it handles this use case and copy it to your script (but I think it will also grab it as a popup)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd remove the `target=_blank` attribute on the element and then click it.

```
await page.$eval("a.browser-button", el => el.removeAttribute("target"))
```

Then click it and it will open in the same window.  Unless you're really determined to test it as is.

Answer (score 5):

Handling new pages is documented [here](https://playwright.dev/docs/pages#handling-new-pages)

You can capture the new page from the click event.

```js
const [newPage] = await Promise.all([
  context.waitForEvent('page'),
  page.locator('a[target="_blank"]').click() // Opens a new tab
])
await newPage.waitForLoadState();
console.log(await newPage.title());
```